# How does EEC/FADEC recognize/anticipate engine acceleration/deceleration?

Tags: jet-engine, avionics

So I'm wondering, when the engine runs at idle and the pilot sets a higher thrust level, what exactly happens, that the EEC/FADEC recognizes, that I want to accelerate? My professor said, it's anticipating the upcoming acceleration through:

- $TRA > TRA_{threshold}$
- $pt_3 < pt_{3_{min}}$ (cabin bleed)
- $N2/\sqrt\theta < N2/\sqrt\theta_{idle}$ with $\theta = Tt2/T_{t ref}$

I get that the TRA (throttle lever angle) is higher than my previous one, hence I just raised it. But why exactly would pt_3 be lower than pt3_min, and why is $N2/\sqrt\theta$ smaller than idle? That would indicate that Tt2 has increased.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to go ask your professor for clarification.  But let's look at it this way: what would it mean if $Pt3 > Pt3_{min}$ and $N2/\sqrt{\theta}>N2/\sqrt{\theta}_{idle}$. It means that the engine is probably NOT at idle. So in that situation, if you move the throttle, you probably do want to increase thrust, but not *from idle*.  The EEC may have different control schedules for idle vs above idle operation.